# How to use complete Dark Mode in Code Blocks 20.03?

Tags: codeblocks

I have tried to install the dark theme and it worked, but only for the area where you can write your code, not for the whole app. Is there a possibility to change the complete colour theme of the app, like in VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set a "dark mode" theme in CodeBlocks.
CodeBlocks is built on the basis of wxWidgets libraries, which currently do not support "dark mode" themes.